# Datalist disapearing in a simple vue example

Tags: vue.js, datalist

Try to select from datalist while a data property is updated on a interval.

What is wrong in my code?

http://jsfiddle.net/startflorin/gr6b1h7j/18

Mounted intervals:

```js
setInterval((ctx) => { ctx.notification = "111"; }, 500, this);
setInterval((ctx) => { ctx.notification = "222"; }, 500, this);
```

Data:

```js
data: {
    notification: null,
    demoList:[
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "option 1",
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "option 2",
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: "option 3",
        },
    ],
},
```

My HTML code:

```html
<div>
    {{ notification }}
</div>

<input list='demoList' v-on:change="selectSymbolList(target.value)">

<datalist id="demoList">
    <option v-for="item in this.demoList" v-bind:value="item.name" v-bind:key="item.id">{{ item.name }}</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cache the rendering of `<input>` and `<datalist>` (to isolate them from unrelated changes in the component's template), put them into a [component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html):

```js
Vue.component('demo-list', {
  props: ['items'],
  template: `<div>
    <input list='demoList'>
    <datalist id="demoList">
      <option v-for="item in items" v-bind:value="item.name" v-bind:key="item.id">{{ item.name }}</option>
    </datalist>
  </div>`
})
```

*Note this example requires the [runtime compiler](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#runtimecompiler) to compile the [`template` string](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#template). Otherwise, [`render` functions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#render) would be required instead of `template`.*

Then use the component in your app's template:

```html
<div id="app">
  <div>{{ notification }}</div>

  <demo-list :items="demoList"></demo-list>
</div>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/wvJjpry?editors=1010)